# Finding the associated unit eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Background**

Find the eigenvalues $λ_1<λ_2$ and two associated unit eigenvectors of the symmetric matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-7&12\\12&11\end{bmatrix}$$

**My work so far**

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-7-λ&12\\12&11-λ\end{bmatrix}=λ^2-4λ-221=(λ+13)(λ-17)$$

Thus

$$λ_1=-13$$
$$λ_2=17$$

To find the solution set for $λ_1$

$$\begin{bmatrix}6&12\\12&24\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$x_1=-2x_2$$
$$x_2=x_2$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
and the solution set for $λ_2$

$$\begin{bmatrix}-24&12\\12&-6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{-1}{2}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$x_1=\frac{1}{2}x_2$$
$$x_2=x_2$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I'm unsure how to get the associated unit eigenvectors. Would I plug these into the quadratic formula to find the solutions? For example, for $λ_2$

$$\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2+1^2}=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{4})+1}=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that I'm off here, but just took a guess.

Comment: Unit eigenvector simply means eigenvector with length (norm) $1$. So if you have the vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$, then the associated unit vector is $$u=\frac{v}{\|v\|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @AnuragA That's brilliant! I wasn't sure of the difference between unit eigenvector and eigenvector, but your explanation was superb and it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly found for $\lambda_{1}=-13$ the eigenspace is $(−2x_{2},x_{2})$ with $x_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$. So if you want the unit eigenvector just solve:

$(−2x_{2})^2+x_{2}^2=1^2$, which geometrically is the intersection of the eigenspace with the unit circle.